# QGIS Voronoi Polygons Float Division by zero

Tags: qgis, geometry, voronoi-thiessen

I have created a vector which is a connection to Sql Server. I then select Vector > Geometry Tools > Voronoi Polygons. I select my input layer and a temporary file for my Voronoi polygons. I get the float  division by zero error and the file is empty that is supposed to be created. I am new to QGIS and am baffled as to what I am doing wrong. I have used the Check Validity menu item and the geometry in the input layer is valid. Also where do I get to select the grouping for my input data for the polygons generated ?. Any ideas anyone?

I should add that I get the same error for Delaunay triangulation algorithm. There is something I am missing but I an unaware of what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what version of QGIS you're using, but if it's 2.18 there appears to be a [known issue](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15825) which is fairly recent.

It happens when no polygons are created, so the fixed version will just give you a different, more informative error message.

**You should check you're doing this on a points layer**. I managed to get the same if I load in a shapefile of type polygon. Normally the dialog only allows you to select point layers, but allows you to open other files using the <kbd>...</kbd> button.

Comment: Yeah I am using 2.18 but I am about to change to an earlier version. I do need a more informative error message.

Comment: is it a points layer? if not, i suspect reverting to an older version won't help. If it is a points layer, something else might be the problem.

Comment: It is a points layer

Comment: It is failing as well. Slightly different in that it just hangs and never creates the result. I can not see where the error is defined though.

Comment: i think the error you see could be anything that caused the voronoi to fail for any reason. (It's caused by having no output). It's impossible to tell without the data. You could try looking for duplicate points (two or more points at same exact coordinates), other than that don't know what else to suggest :/

Comment: So duplicates would make it fail would it ?

Comment: not tested that - just a hunch

Comment: The reason it was failing is because it was a multipoint event though it was only 1 point. I forgot I had to change this when I was extracting it elsewhere. So it works now thanks for your help.